# preg_replace what expression to use to replace specific text and add a period

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Say I have a string as:

```
$orig = "Go 'outisde'Please";
```

And i want to replace the word 'outside' (must be in single quotes) with the following:

```
$replaceWith = "OUT";
```

And if the orig string has alphanumeric characters following it (not spaces or special, or quotes) then add a period after the replaceWith

So the expected output would become:

```
$out = "Go 'OUT'.Please";
```

Here is what I have so far, but I am missing the part that adds a period as explained above.

```
$out = preg_replace("/'outside'/", $replaceWith, $orig); //handle single quotes
```

This would evaluate as:

```
$out = "Go 'OUT'Please";
```

My guess is there is a fancy regex that can help me with it. I tried searching and couldn't find anything directly for my use case. Thank you.

Comment: You'd need a `preg_replace_callback` to determine if an alphanum is after the outter. `'outisde'(\p{alnum})?` typical. If so, add your `'OUT' + \. + $1` if needed, or just `'OUT'` if not.

Comment: `$out = str_replace("'outside'", "'OUT'." $orig)`, why do you need a regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because I only want the period if the string it is replacing has an alphanumeric character proceeding the match. If it was one static word then I wouldn't need regex, but in my case its matching against many thousands of strings.

Comment: Can you do it in two steps? First replace `'outside'(\w)` with `'OUT'.$1`, then replace `'outside'` with `'OUT'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
$orig = "Go 'outside'Please";
$replaceWith = "OUT";
$out = preg_replace_callback("/'outside'([a-zA-Z0-9])?/", fn($m) => empty($m[1]) ? $replaceWith : "$replaceWith.${m[1]}", $orig); 
echo $out; // => Go OUT.Please
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MPO9F).

Here, `'outside'([a-zA-Z0-9])?` matches `'outside'` and then captures a letter or a digit into Group 1 with an optional `([a-zA-Z0-9])?` pattern.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is the `$replaceWith` + `.` + Group 1 value, else, the whole match is replaced with the `$replaceWith` string.